# Per row validation while importing CSV file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm Importing a CSV file to a livewire component and trying to run some validation for each row of the file but I'm having problems doing this. It seems that my validation is doing nothing.

Here is how my Livewire component looks like:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Modals;

use Validator;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Http\Traits\Csv;
use App\Models\AccountUser;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ImportExtensions extends Component
{

use WithFileUploads;

public $clientID;
public $showModal = false;
public $upload;
public $columns;
public $fieldColumnMap = [
    'first_name' => '',
    'last_name' => '',
    'email' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'extension' => '',
    'user_type' => '',
];

protected $rules = [
        'fieldColumnMap.first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'fieldColumnMap.last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'fieldColumnMap.email' => 'required|max:255',
        'fieldColumnMap.password' => 'required|max:255',
        'fieldColumnMap.extension' => 'required|max:255',
        'fieldColumnMap.user_type' => 'required|max:255',
];

protected $validationAttributes = [
    'fieldColumnMap.first_name' => 'First Name',
    'fieldColumnMap.last_name' => 'Last Name',
    'fieldColumnMap.email' => 'Email',
    'fieldColumnMap.password' => 'Password',
    'fieldColumnMap.extension' => 'Extension',
    'fieldColumnMap.user_type' => 'User Type',
];

public function updatingUpload($value)
{
    Validator::make(
        ['upload' => $value],
        ['upload' => 'required|mimes:txt,csv'],
    )->validate();
}

public function updatedUpload()
{
    $this->columns = Csv::from($this->upload)->columns();
    $this->guessWhichColumnsMapToWhichFields();
}

public function import()
{
    // Validate that you are importing any data
    $this->validate();

    $importCount = 0;
    Csv::from($this->upload)
    ->eachRow( function ($row) use (&$importCount){
        $eachRow = $this->extractFieldsFromRow($row);

        //Validate the data of each Row to make to make sure you don't import duplicate records   
        $this->validateOnly(collect($eachRow), [
            'fieldColumnMap.first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'fieldColumnMap.last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'fieldColumnMap.email' => 'required|max:255|email|unique:account_users, email',
            'fieldColumnMap.extension' => 'required|numeric|unique:account_users, extension',
            'fieldColumnMap.password' => 'required|max:255',
            'fieldColumnMap.user_type' => 'required|in:user,admin',
        ]);

        //If validation fails, it should skip the create extension part and run the next row

        //If validation pass, then create the Extension
        AccountUser::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'account_id' => $this->clientID,
            'first_name' => $eachRow['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $eachRow['last_name'],
            'email' => $eachRow['email'],
            'password' => $eachRow['password'],
            'extension' => $eachRow['extension'],
            'user_type' => $eachRow['user_type'],
        ]);
        $importCount++;
    });
    $this->reset();
    $this->emit('refreshExtensions');
    $this->notify('Successfully Imported '.$importCount.' Extensions');
}
```

Also, how can I make so that if the validation fails it goes to the next row instead of trying to create the extension.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but why don't you just make all the rows of the CSV in to a collection via `collect($rowsOrStmt)` and then use `->reject` and run a simple laravel validator in that closure? for the rest you could then tack on `->each` to do your model work... I mean it seems like you don't need the validation messages anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But how would that looks like? Anything that I tried uses the rules from `protected $rules` but those are not the ones that I need for each field of the CSV. I guess what I could do is, if any line fails just throw an error. but again, the validation is the part that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create custom rules for just this. if one row fails validation, I just throw an error. So, basically either all rows pass or all fails.
Here is how it looks like now:

```
public function import()
{
    // Validate that you are importing any data
    $this->validate();

    $importCount = 0;
    Csv::from($this->upload)
    ->eachRow( function ($row) use (&$importCount){
        $eachRow = $this->extractFieldsFromRow($row);

        $validatedData = Validator::make([
            'first_name' => $eachRow['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $eachRow['last_name'],
            'email' => $eachRow['email'],
            'password' => $eachRow['password'],
            'extension' => $eachRow['extension'],
            'user_type' => $eachRow['user_type'],
            ],[
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:account_users',
            'extension' => 'required|numeric|unique:account_users',
            'password' => 'required|max:255',
            'user_type' => 'required|in:user,admin',
        ],);

        if($validatedData->fails()){
            $this->notify(['error','Oops something went wrong!']);
        }else{
            AccountUser::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'account_id' => $this->clientID,
                'first_name' => $eachRow['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $eachRow['last_name'],
                'email' => $eachRow['email'],
                'password' => $eachRow['password'],
                'extension' => $eachRow['extension'],
                'user_type' => $eachRow['user_type'],
            ]);
            $importCount++;
        }
    });

    $this->reset();
    $this->emit('refreshExtensions');
    if($importCount!=0) $this->notify(['success','Successfully Imported '.$importCount.' Extensions']);
}
```